# WooCommerce - Init wc functions after ajax page refresh

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I have been using smoothState-JS to refresh pages via Ajax. After changing to the checkout/cart page from WooCommerce, certain functions don't work anymore.

I have 2 options:

1. Re-Init WC function after Ajax request
2. Don't use Ajax to go to a checkout/cart page

I would prefer the second option, I do have the first one working (but the second one would be neat).

So my question is: Is there a way to re-init WC scripts after an Ajax pagereload?